# Converting from latex to markdown with pandoc, images not converted

Tags: latex, markdown, pandoc

I'm trying to convert a latex file to markdown using Pandoc.  The latex file contains linked images, for example like this:

```
\begin{figure}[htbp]
\begin{center}
\leavevmode
\scalebox{0.4}{\includegraphics{microsatsFigures/Figure_traceView.png}}
\end{center}
\caption{The Traces view}
\label{traces}
\end{figure}
```

However in the markdown file all I get is

```
::: center
:::
```

Is this a known limitation of Pandoc, or is there some command I'm missing that will convert the image instructions?  The command I used in pandoc was just the standard format:

```
pandoc -f latex -t markdown Inputfile.tex -o Outputfile.md
```

Comment: Does it work if you use `\begin{figure}[htbp]\centering\includegraphics[scale=0.4]{./microsatsFigures/Figure_traceView.png}\caption{The Traces view}\label{traces}\end{figure}` instead?

Comment: It looks like it would work but there is a broken link to the actual figure.  But unfortunately its not practical for me to convert way the figures are written in the latex as there's hundreds of figures.  I think it might be quicker for me to just reformat the markdown files to add the figures again.

Comment: It would be better to convert the way your figures are written. By using the `center` environment instead of `\centering` the vertical space around your figures is wrong.